# caliburn micro - run code when view is visible?

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I need to run some code (let's say to show message box) right after the view is displayed. I tried to override `OnInitialize`, `OnViewLoaded` or `OnViewAttached` but it's always the same. The View is not fully displayed yet.

I use some animation when displaying view but at the same time need to load some data into grid. If I put data load into `OnInitialize`, `OnViewLoaded` or `OnViewAttached` the animation is not smooth as it's kind of happening the same time when loading data.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like you are running into the grid rendering the bound data and therefore the ui thread locking a little as it loads. Why not use a coroutine to wait for the animation to complete then load or bind the data

Answer (score 0):

Give something like this a try - use a couroutine to wait for the animation to complete before binding the grid:

```
private IEnumerator<IResult> ViewModelStartup()
{
    yield return new WaitForAnimation("AnimationName");
    BindData();
}
```

(note - you can load the data async, but just don't assign it)

Then when your form loads:

```
private void OnViewAttached()
{
    Coroutine.BeginExecute(ViewModelStartup(), new ActionExecutionContext() { View = this.GetView() });
}
```

(the code above might not be 100%... I think `View` must be `FrameworkElement` in `ActionExecutionContext` so cast as needed or create a wrapper class)

The implementation of the `WaitForAnimation` coroutine would search the view for a named animation and wait for it to complete before firing the callback. You should probably just fire the callback if the animation could not be found. The couroutine could be used on multiple views.

(Coroutines must implement `IResult` have a look at the docs on the CM codeplex site for info)

http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=IResult%20and%20Coroutines&referringTitle=Documentation